Sharepoint list synchronization with Excel VBA seems not to be working anymore if the table is too wide
I developed in the past an application running on Excel VBA that has for a long time managed the synchronization between an excel file and a sharepoint list. This is managed with the code in the following that, in the case of this stub, adds an item to the local mirror of the sharepoint list (worksheet "SPLocalMirror") and then synchronizes the resulting table to Sharepoint. The item is taken from an array and added by appending to the target table a new row that is later updated to the original SharePoint list. The code comes with two alternative options A and B. Option A is pasting on the target range a bidimensional array by using the Application.Index function, option B is pasting a monodimensional array by simply assigning to the target range the value of a monodimensional array.
I recently noticed this is not working properly anymore when the pasted data stretch beyond column 20 of the target worksheet. When trying to paste the array to SharePoint mirror worksheet (SPLocalMirror) with both option A and option B, the action is failing (without any error, it simply doesn't paste the new values) if the pasting stretch beyond column 20 of the target worksheet. Be aware it is not depending on the width of the table: it fails also with a table ten columns wide if the right edge of the table range exceeds column 20 of the target worksheet. Since both actions work properly just if I stop before column 20 this seems to be a bug rather than a planned constraint. Of course the workaround can be to assign cells one at a time with a sort of For-Next cycle but, since the data are quite big-sized, this is seriously slowing down the data processing. The problem occurs only when the statement is applied to the table mirroring the SP list. If the same statement is applied to whatever range of the excel file the result is the one regularly expected. So it looks like a constraint imposed by Sharepoint synchronization functionality. Is it a known problem? Is there anyway to work it around?
SPWorksheetName="SPLocalMirror"
For Each GenericSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If GenericSheet.Name = SPWorksheetName Then
        NameExists = True
    End If
Next    
If Not NameExists Then
    Dim SPLocal As Worksheet
        Set SPLocal = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
        SPLocal.Name = SPWorksheetName
Else
        ErrorMsg = "A worksheet exists with name SPLocalMirror. Please remove or rename before running the macro"
        Exit Sub
End If
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SPWorksheetName)
SPImportedTable = ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcExternal, Array(SPURL, SPListName, SPViewName), True, xlYes, ws.Range("A1"))
Dim SharepointAddMatrix As Variant
Dim SharepointAddArray As Variant
ReDim SharepointAddMatrix(1 To 1, 1 To 20)
ReDim SharepointAddArray(1 To 20)
SharepointAddArray(1)="Albert"
(...)
SharepointAddMatrix(1,1)="Abigail"
(...)

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SPWorksheet).Select
SharepointWidth = 20
CounterSPRows = 10
If CounterSPRows > 2 Then
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(SPImportedTableName).Resize Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(CounterSPRows, 68))
End If

'Option A
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SPWorksheet)
    .Range(.Cells(CounterSPRows, 2), .Cells(CounterSPRows, SharepointWidth + 1)).Value = Application.Index(SharepointColumnAddMatrix, 1, 0)
End With

'Option B
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SPWorksheet)
    .Range(.Cells(CounterSPRows, 8), .Cells(CounterSPRows, SharepointWidth + 7)).Value = SharepointColumnAddArray
End With


'The following updates the data to SP list and delete the mirror worksheet
SPImportedTable.UpdateChanges xlListConflictDialog
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SPWorksheet).Delete

I tried all other ways to do the same job but it seems this 20th column constraint is a general topic

If you have a ListObject then you should be working with (eg) its DataBodyRange when referring to a range within the table.  List object cell coordinates and worksheet cell coordinates don't always match....

Unfortunately it is not working as well. Basically the following code is working:
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SPWorksheet).ListObjects(SPImportedTableName).DataBodyRange.Resize(1, 19).Offset(22, 1) = Application.Index(SharepointColumnAddMatrix, 1, 0)...
Whilst the following is not working:
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SPWorksheet).ListObjects(SPImportedTableName).DataBodyRange.Resize(1, 20).Offset(22, 1) = Application.Index(SharepointColumnAddMatrix, 1, 0)

OK I can replicate that - assigning the row values from an array fails, but adding values one-by-one to the new row does work (even when there are over 20 columns).  Not all columns in the new row seem to be editable though...

Adding values one-by-one works fine but here comes a problem of processing time. The bottleneck in terms of time is accessing excel table not so much the size. So it approximately takes the same time to paste an entire array as a single cell. This means that to paste an array with 60 elements one-by-one takes 60 times what required pasting the entire array in one shot.
Until a couple of weeks ago the latter approach worked, but it recently stopped working as described above, due maybe to some updates that messed up this functionality, and this is putting me in big trouble.. :-(
